# Reading return data from a Solidity `call`

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly, type-casting

Given a call to an external contract,

```
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = addr.call(abiEncoding);
```

how do I read a single value of a given type from the return data, without using assembly?

The assembly version would be, e.g. for `bool` return type,

```
if (success) {
    bool boolVal;
    if (returnData.length >= 1) {
        assembly {
            boolVal := mload(add(returnData, 32))
        }
    } else {
        boolVal = false;
    }
}
```

This sort of pattern seems to be needed for any return type other than `string`, because (as far as I can tell) you can't accomplish this by merely casting, e.g. if you expect a `bytes4` as the return value, you can't just go `bytes4(returnData)`.

However assembly sections are always flagged in security audits as potential issues, and additionally, assembly potentially makes your code unportable in future to other blockchains or other VMs, etc. -- so surely there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returndata will be abi encoded bytes. You must decode these first providing the correct types.

Example:

```
(uint256 a, address b) = abi.decode(returnData, (uint256, address));
```